# linux Find Command not finishing

Tags: linux, rhel, find

I have a directory
/home/history/customer

```
find /home/history/customer -type f -mtime +90 -print
```

there are no files older than 90 days. but this command just doesn't stop running and doesn't return anything in the terminal.

if I change the command to 60 days - it returns results for me.

any ideas?

Comment: How long did you wait for it to finish, and how many files are under `/home/history/customer`?

Comment: Since `find` will go through all the files (and check every single one's modification date) no matter whether you search for files newer than 60 days or 90 days, I don't see an obvious technical difference between the two. Can you please run `/usr/bin/time find /home/history/customer -type f -mtime +60 -print > /dev/null` and report the result?

Comment: Try the -mount option to keep find in current filesystem.